# Delphi HTTP App raising error when loading files into streams

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, httpapplication, tfilestream

I've been working on an HTTP Web Server Application (via `TIdHTTPWebBrokerBridge`) and have a little issue when it comes to loading files into streams (`TFileStream`) to be sent back to the client. It doesn't happen every time, but quite randomly... I keep getting an exception...

`Cannot open file "C:\SomePath\SomeFile.html". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

It happens on this line:

`Str:= TFileStream.Create('C:\SomePath\SomeFile.html', fmOpenRead);`

(Str being a `TFileStream`)

I'm assuming the message speaks for its self, but I absolutely need to avoid it. This exception only happens in debug mode, but I need to debug this thing without worrying about getting this message all the time.

Strangely, most of the time, the file is loaded and sent back anyway.

How could I go about avoiding this? And why might it not allow me to open it more than once, even if its read only?

Comment: Well, you don't use the share mode in your code... perhaps using `fmShareDenyWrite` or `fmShareDenyNone` is all thats needed to fix your problem, see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TFileStream.Create

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @ain stated in the comment - you are missing the share mode in your Constructor.

Change this

```
Str:= TFileStream.Create('C:\SomePath\SomeFile.html', fmOpenRead);
```

to this

```
Str:= TFileStream.Create('C:\SomePath\SomeFile.html', fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyNone);
```

Comment: Yup, that did it! That goes to point out to never completely trust any sample source code you find on the internet :P

Comment: I wish the default open+share mode in Delphi was fmOpenRead + fmShareDenyWrite that would solve so many issues that starters have.